# Volume density on a Riemannian manifold as a measure

Tags: measure-theory, riemannian-geometry

I am having some trouble in seeing exactly how the Riemannian density form gives rise to a measure on $\text{Borel(M)}$.

Let $(M,g)$ be a Riemannian manifold. We have the Riemannian density $\mu_g$. Now we can define $\int f \mu_g $ for any compactly supported continuous function.

I guess the way to introuduce a measure on $\text{Borel(M)}$ is as follows:
For an open subset $U \subseteq M$ we would like to define $\mu(U) = \int _U \mu_g$, where the integral is taken on the submanifold $U$ with the induced metric from $(M,g)$.

The problem is that the conatant function $1_U$ is not compactly supporteed on $U$ so I am not sure how to define it.*

Even if we did that, how do we extend the measure to the whole Borel sigma-algebra? (via some machinery of measure theory?)
How do we go on proving sigma-additivity of the measure?

Any explanation or a detailed reference would be welcomed.

---

*Maybe using somehow the positivity of the integral, if $U$ is contained in a compact set $K$ we can try using a sequence of approximating bump functions which are $1$ on $U$ and decrease faster and faster outside $U$ and are all equal to $0$ outside of $K$. Maybe if the sequence of integrals converge the limit is $\mu(U)$?

But this does not work if $U$ is not contained in a compact set.

Comment: Doesn't the Riesz representation theorem furnish you with an honest-to-goodness measure once you've defined the integral on the continuous, compactly supported functions?

Answer (score 1):

Given that you have defined your integral for functions with compact support, you can extend the set of functions it acts on by using a [Partition of Unity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_unity):

> A partition of unity can be used to define the integral (with respect to a volume form) of a function defined over a manifold: One first defines the integral of a function whose support is contained in a single coordinate patch of the manifold; then one uses a partition of unity to define the integral of an arbitrary function; finally one shows that the definition is independent of the chosen partition of unity.

This is a set of functions $\phi_i$ which can be made to have compact support (see e.g. [Chapter 4 - Partitions of Unity and Smooth Functions](https://www.math.lsu.edu/~lawson/Chapter4.pdf)) so that integral of a general function $f$ is defined via:
$$\int_X f d\mu_g = \int_X f \sum_i \phi_i d\mu_g = \sum_i \int_X f \phi_i d\mu_g$$

Comment: Maybe I miss something, but the sum could contain an infinite number of terms, the locl-finitness of partitions of unity seems to me irrelevant here. (Since you sum over integrals which are numbers, not over functions). Also, if the support of $f$ is not compact, then you cannot assume you have a finite cover of it by chart's domains.

Comment: Maybe it does not matter since all the integrals which interest me are supposed to be positive, hence the sum is always definedm but might be infinite which is a legitimate value for a measure to obtain.

Comment: @AsafShachar - Sure I've removed that statement as it was misleading.  Certainly the sum can be infinity - e.g. the constant function, with the manifold $\mathbb{R}$ with the standard metric.

Comment: I guess everyone disagrees with Spivak - see Calculus on Manifolds.